# <use> как управлять размерами

Tags: html, css, svg

не могу разобраться как указать явный размер в 21рх для иконки, когда она вставлена через , явно размер задаётся только для родительской  а у  размеры меняются только с помощью viewbox, указанного у родительской  и задаются в каких-то внутренних единицах. Методом проб и ошибок определил что вот так можно задать 21рх размер ,благодаря перебору значений атрибута viewbox="0 0 39 39"

```
    <svg width="21" height="21" viewbox="0 0 39 39" >
      <use href="./svg/floppy.svg#floppy">
    </svg>
```

но может есть способ чтобы в одно движение размер задать для `<use>` без перебора значений

Comment: По-видимому, у используемого узла viewbox не задан. Поэтому его приходится указывать при использовании. Должно быть примерно так: ```<symbol id="floppy" viewBox="0 0 39 39">```

Comment: "через...." что?